# pandas returning column name as value if column name matches value of another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been stuck on this for a few weeks now....

df1:

| 2 | 1/1/2021 | 1/2/2021 | 1/3/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name |  |  |  |
| a | door | nan | house |
| b | nan | key | door |
| c | nan | house | key |
| d | house | key | nan |

df2:

| 2 | key | door | house |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name |  |  |  |
| a | nan | nan | nan |
| b | nan | nan | nan |
| c | nan | nan | nan |
| d | nan | nan | nan |

desired output=

df2:

| 2 | key | door | house |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name |  |  |  |
| a | nan | 1/1/2021 | 1/3/2021 |
| b | 1/2/2021 | 1/3/2021 | nan |
| c | 1/3/2021 | nan | 1/2/2021 |
| d | 1/2/2021 | nan | 1/1/2021 |

Comment: is there a reason you need df2 at all? In your current example all information required is already in df1, therefore transforming df1 should be enough. Please elaborate on the use of df2

Comment: I set up df2 with column names of all values that could be in df1 under the timestamps in hopes I could perform something like index-match in excel (df.lookup). if possible to accomplish without df2 it's beyond my comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) + [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot-table) with `aggfunc='first'` to get the first match

```
df2 = (
    df1.stack()
        .reset_index()
        .pivot_table(index='Name', columns=0, values=2, aggfunc='first')
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

```
          door     house       key
Name                              
a     1/1/2021  1/3/2021       NaN
b     1/3/2021       NaN  1/2/2021
c          NaN  1/2/2021  1/3/2021
d          NaN  1/1/2021  1/2/2021
```

Optional [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex) from `df2`:

```
df2 = (
    df1.stack()
        .reset_index()
        .pivot_table(index='Name', columns=0, values=2, aggfunc='first')
        .reindex(index=df2.index, columns=df2.columns)
)
```

```
2          key      door     house
Name                              
a          NaN  1/1/2021  1/3/2021
b     1/2/2021  1/3/2021       NaN
c     1/3/2021       NaN  1/2/2021
d     1/2/2021       NaN  1/1/2021
```

---

DataFrames Used:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    '1/1/2021': {'a': 'door', 'b': nan, 'c': nan, 'd': 'house'},
    '1/2/2021': {'a': nan, 'b': 'key', 'c': 'house',
                 'd': 'key'},
    '1/3/2021': {'a': 'house', 'b': 'door', 'c': 'key',
                 'd': nan}
}).rename_axis(index='Name', columns=2)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': {'a': nan, 'b': nan, 'c': nan, 'd': nan},
    'door': {'a': nan, 'b': nan, 'c': nan, 'd': nan},
    'house': {'a': nan, 'b': nan, 'c': nan, 'd': nan}
}).rename_axis(index='Name', columns=2)
```

Comment: Thx for the copyable data.

Comment: Ty for the copyable example.

Comment: @Plentyoftime as a addendum to that please don't mark it as the accepted answer until it actually solves the problem and works as expected =)

Comment: Good. Progress has been made no more `KeyError`! So now, which date do you expect to get if there are multiple dates for the same item.

Comment: Okay. So I'm going to interpret "simply" match as the first match found similar to excel's lookup. Try now with the update using `pivot_table`. Also comments aren't meant for extended discussion. Would you mind cleaning up any comments that are no longer relevant to the current question and answer? Thank you.

Comment: Hey @henry, so this works. I’ve verified all columns are grouped correctly. For some reason I am getting “2” for all column names instead of the “key door house” like your example shows. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You may actually not even need `df2`. What about

```
>>> df1.stack().reset_index().set_index(['Name', 0])[2].unstack()
0         door     house       key
Name                              
a     1/1/2021  1/3/2021       NaN
b     1/3/2021       NaN  1/2/2021
c          NaN  1/2/2021  1/3/2021
d          NaN  1/1/2021  1/2/2021
```

<sub>*Tested thanks to @Henry's copiable data*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can combine melt and pivot:

```
df1.reset_index().melt('Name').dropna().pivot('Name', 'value', 2)

value      door     house       key
Name                               
a      1/1/2021  1/3/2021       NaN
b      1/3/2021       NaN  1/2/2021
c           NaN  1/2/2021  1/3/2021
d           NaN  1/1/2021  1/2/2021
```

Comment: Maybe drop the `NaN` column?

Comment: @HenryEcker, ah you are right. Nice stack/unstack solution btw.